# Need Help with a regular expression not replacing all instances of an expression

Tags: c#, regex

Been banging my head against the wall on this one all day and am getting close to my wits end on this. Looking for some fresh perspective.

**Sample Input Text:**
 (line breaks added for clarity, not in actual data )

```
</div>#My Novel<br />  
##Chapter1<br />  
It was a dark and stormy night<br />
##Chapter 2<br />
The End
```

**Desired Output**

```
</div><h1>My Novel</h1><br />
<h1>Chapter1</h1><br />  
It was a dark and stormy night<br />  
<h1>Chapter 2</h1><br />  
The End
```

**Actual Output**

```
</div><h1>My Novel</h1><br />
##Chapter1<br />  
It was a dark and stormy night<br />  
<h1>Chapter 2</h1><br />  
The End
```

**Here is the match expression**
(formatted for easy reading, comments/linebreaks are not in expression)

```
(?<preamble>
    (                             
        ([<]\/\w+\d*[>])|([<]\w+\d*\s*\/[>])   #</tag> or <tag />
    )
    \s*  #optional whitespace                       
)

(?<hashmarks>
    \#{1,6}      #1-6 hash marks
)    

(?<content>
    .+?          #header content
 )      

(?<closing>
    ([<](br|\/\s*br|br\s*\/)[>])   #<br>,</br>, or <br />
)
```

**Here is the replace Expression**

```
${preamble}<h1>${content}</h1>${closing}
```

If it matters I am using the following C# regex.replace overload:

```
Regex.Replace(Source,SrchExp,ReplExpr,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

**The question (finally)**
Can anyone see why it is replacing #My Novel and ##Chapter 2, but not ##Chapter 1?

Sorry for the long post, and hopefully I didn't munge anything trying to format it to make it readible for SO.

**Update:**

One more thing that might help. Adding an extra break tag right after "Novel" makes the provided code start working perfectly. No idea why yet.

**Sample Input Text (modified):**

```
</div>#My Novel<br /><br />
##Chapter1<br />  
It was a dark and stormy night<br />
##Chapter 2<br />
The End
```

Comment: Why does you data start with </div>, an end-tag?

Comment: The original input data will normally be longer, but since I am not matching on anything before the first end tag, I omitted it in the sample to make it easier to read. If it makes you feel better, substitute <br /> for the </div> tag. The problem is identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that was actually tested and appears to work.

The issue is that once a match is found, the search continues exactly where the first one left off. As a result, the closing `<br />` of `#My Novel` will not be captured again, and so `#Chapter1` is missed.

To capture `#Chapter1`-like constructs anyway, we can use a [lookbehind assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(VS.71).aspx). Lookbehinds enforce the presence of the prefix, even if it extends before the current position. This also prevents the need to drop it in the replacement string:

- Replace `(?<preamble>` with `(?<=`
- Then in the replacement string, remove the `${preamble}` portion.

The overall search expression now looks like:

```
(?<=             # removed the preamble capture and replaced with a lookbehind
    (                             
        ([<]\/\w+\d*[>])|([<]\w+\d*\s*\/[>])   #</tag> or <tag />
    )
    \s*  #optional whitespace                               
)

(?<hashmarks>
    \#{1,6}      #1-6 hash marks
)    

(?<content>
    .+?          #header content
 )      

(?<closing>
    ([<](br|\/\s*br|br\s*\/)[>])   #<br>,</br>, or <br />
)
```

And the replacement string looks like:

```
<h1>${content}</h1>${closing}
```

Our output is now faithfully:

```
</div><h1>My Novel</h1><br />
<h1>Chapter1</h1><br />
It was a dark and stormy night<br />
<h1>Chapter 2</h1><br />
The End
```

Comment: You are the man! The lookbehind assertion worked like a charm.

Comment: You also ought to be able to replace `(?<closing>` with a look*ahead* assertion: `(?=`